# Swift - I want to access information from the SceneDelegate.swift in my viewcontroller

Tags: swift

When using an `AppDelegate`, this line of code would allow me to send variables between app delegate and the view controller.

```
let firstName = AppDelegate.shared().givenName
```

What can I do for `sceneDelegate`?

Answer (score 0):

Well I can suggest you using User Defaults like that:

```
// Set
UserDefaults.standard.set(self.currentZoomLevel, forKey: "zoomLevel")
// Read
if let zoomLevel = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "zoomLevel") as? CGFloat {
                return zoomLevel
            }
```

Another approach should be like that

```
var window: UIWindow?

// On your scene delegate you have an instance variable Window
       func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
           guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
           let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            self.window = window
}
```

With window object, you can access the navigation controller and access your viewController directly:

```
var wantedViewController: DesiredViewController?
    let _ = window?.rootViewController?.children.forEach({ navigation in
                if let navController = navigation as? UINavigationController {
                    if let tabBar = navController.viewControllers.filter({ viewController in
                        viewController is MyTabBarController
                    }).first {
                        if let container = tabBar.children.filter({ $0 is ContainerViewController }).first as? ContainerViewController {
                            if let innerViewController = container.children.filter({ $0 is RootViewController }).first as? RootViewController {
                                wantedViewController = innerViewController.orderedViewControllers.filter({ $0 is DesiredViewController }).first as? DesiredViewController
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
```

This code is a little bit complex because of my structure on the project, my view controller is inside a TabController, probably yours can be not that complex and you will find the view controller easier.
Just debug and see how it happens.